# How to use Find or Find<T> on DbContext in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

***NB** I'm not asking how to find/filter entities in the DB. I'm not asking about the difference between `Find` and `Where`. I'm not asking about the implication of generics.*

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.find?view=efcore-5.0), the `DbContext` provides methods `Find` and `Find<T>`. Usually, I go through the `DbSet` but noticing that there's `Add()` on both the context directly and the DB set, I wanted to see what will happen if I try to filter directly on the context too, instead of the DB set.

I haven't found a single example of such call, though. A lot of information on going through the DB set and the differences mentioned in the disclaimer at the top. But I see no sample showing usage of `Find()` nor `Find<T>()` directly on the context.

Is it possible at all and if so, how? Intellisense is cryptic...

Comment: Using `Find` when you want find by primary key. Noticed that primary key can be complex. For example, you have table `Person` with `ID (int)` is primary key then you can passing and integer value into `Find`. You have another table `PersonAddress` with have primary key is `(PersonID, AddressID)`. Then you need pass an anonymous object e.g. `Find(new {1, 2})`.

Comment: @LeVu I considered that possibility but it makes no sense to me as it's not generally coherent. Personally, I'm a great believer in GUIDs so I'm covered but there's a lot of folks who prefer integers for ID and then you end up in a bunch of different entities/instances having the same ID. There will be customers with ID equal to 1234 but also orders, invoices etc. Why would they even release a method despite such circumstances? Seems like I'm missing something (because I trust deeply that the coders at MS have not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does the same thing, but without using the `DbSet`. It works by specifying the `type` (entity) you want to fetch. You just have to specify the type, which must match your DbSet.

> Is it possible at all and if so, how?

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<City> Cities{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
MyContext context = CreateContext() // Or inject it...

// Will return the City which have id == 5. 
object myUntypedCity = context.Find(typeof(City), 5);

// Will return the city which have id == [your guid].
City myTypedCity = context.Find<City>(Guid.NewGuid());
```

As a sidenote; `Add()` on the Context works the same way. It will detect which `type` of entity it is and put it on the correct `DbSet`. I do not know what will happen if you have several `DbSet` using the same `type`.

> why we have a non-generic Find() on the context given that quite a few
> DBs are using integers for IDs, hence ensuring ambiguous ID values
> between different entities/tables

In some scenarios you might not expose the `DbSet` or you only know the `type` of the entity. This can be very handy when making some very generic code where you don't have a typed entity nor know exactly what type of id (primary key) it has. It may be a `Guid` or an `int`. I myself have never found a practical use for  `Find` on the `DbContext`.

Comment: @KonradViltersten As I understood it you was wondering _how to use it_? Not _what it does_? If so, I would gladly put that in the answer as well.

Comment: It's your answer so you put in whatever you see fit. I appreciate a certain elasticity in the content even if it technically speaking goes beyond the exact scope of the original question. However, my comment regarded some remark directed to "Fabio" and it wasn't until now I realized that it must have been a removed comment. I got no notification of it and my brain made a logical boo-boo. What was the (now removed) comment about?

Comment: Also, if you feel like it, it would be interesting to hear your take on why we have a non-generic `Find()` on the context given that quite a few DBs are using integers for IDs, hence ensuring ambiguous ID values between different entities/tables (see the comments below the question).

Comment: @KonradViltersten , you're right. It was an answer to a deleted comment. It was something about `Find` being available on `DbSet` as well.

Comment: Great! I took the liberty to edit it a bit. Combining city and state might be a bit confusing to a new developer. Also, the returned type is obvious as you're using hard and explicit typed variables (as God intended). Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @KonradViltersten, using different types was made because I use different id's for them (int/guid). Now the code would break since you're using guid in one find and int in the other.

Comment: I see your point. However, rest assured, from the reader's point of view (i.e. mine, subjectively), this makes perfect sense in relation to the question asked. You make the distinction perfectly well. THat said - it's your post, you own it. If you feel it's better to change back a portion of the answer, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Find` on a DbSet, the Type of entity is known, so it just needs to Find by the provided ID.

When you use `Find` on the DbContext, you either have to tell EF which `Type` (Entity) to find against from its known mappings, or you can use the Generic version which defines the `Type` of entity to search against.

Why would you use these methods instead of `DbSet.Find`? One example would be where you don't want to expose an aspect of your domain as a `DbSet`. For example if you have a DbSet of Customers, Businesses, etc. that all contain references to Address entities it would be uncommon to ever need to load an Address outside of that scope so you would probably opt not to expose a `DbSet<Address>` in your domain to potentially be abused through convenience. In the case where your DbContext actually does need to locate a particular Address, you could use `DbContext.Find<Address>(addressId)` to load it.

Honestly I don't use `DbContext.Find()`, I don't even use `DbSet.Find()`, I much, much prefer to work with `IQueryable` and projection. But hey, it's an option. :)

Comment: I share your sentiment working with DB sets. It's been **the** way to go. However, lately, I've noticed some Mongo-devs using `Find` and (after initially assuming that's "their" way to go) I discovered that there was `Find` for "normal" DBs too. And reading up on it revealed that it's more performant because it only makes the trip to the DB if there's no copy of the instance in the memory already. So we might be doing it wrong, you and I. And then, I started to poke around to validate/falsify what my experience taught me.

Comment: Looking at it from the law of averages, I don't worry too much. By standardizing on Linq and `IQueryable` I am often selecting select bits of data, or doing things like `Any` check for exists. `Find` *might* save me a DB hit, or it might result in pulling the entire entity if I standardize on it. I want my data layer to be mock-able so `IQueryable` serves as a better default IMO. Querying by ID is a fast operation, and should there be a more critical case and I assume most entries should be already loaded, I can always check `DbSet.Local`.

Comment: Also, since most DbContext instances should be relatively short-lived, and having any significant number of tracked instances within a DbContext can start having a negative performance impact for unrelated operations leading to using features like `AsNoTracking`, `Find` could very well end up hitting the DB most times anyway, or be responsible for overall sluggishness if combined with long-lived, high tracking count DbContexts. (plus potential stale data issues as well)

Comment: You've made two excellent points. I agree with them (as they correlate to the way I'm used to) but you gave me now a neat formulation to convey and motivate that when I'm discussing said issue with colleagues who have a different view. That's my weak point - being able to motivate and influence my peers. And when I fail o do that, eventually I start question my suggestion. (That usually ends poorly for the progess...) So your comment is very valuable to me.